# How to check if a Float variable is negative in java

Tags: java

i am using the following code:

```
//Calculating Profit and Loss
     float difference= sell_amount-buy_amount;
    if (flag == 0) {
        if ((difference<0)) {
            System.out.print("Loss ");
            System.out.println(difference - total_extra);

        } else {

            System.out.println("Profit ");
            System.out.println(difference - total_extra);
        }
    }
```

even if in some inputs, the output is -0.53, it still says profit.. where am i going wrong

Comment: The output is not the `difference` though...It substracts `total_extra` from `difference`.

Comment: If difference is greater than 0, you print difference-total_extra which may very well be negative even if difference>0

Comment: I suggest you step through your code in a debugger.  This is the sort of problem it is designed to solve.

Comment: What hinders you to make the calculation     difference - total_extra before checking the result for being positiv or negativ? You just have the wrong odrder of operation and it stands out fairly obvious.

Answer (score 7):

When you print out the difference, you also remove the value of total_extra.
Thus, let's say diffrence = 0.47 and total_extra = 1. The difference is indeed positive (thus printing "Profit", but when you print the value difference - total_extra, you print out "-0.53"

Comment: -1 @joachim isaksson already posted this in the comments. you just copied

Comment: @PhilippSander Who cares? He posted a correct answer, and he didn't copy the comment verbatim. Who's to say he didn't start writing this answer before that comment was even posted? +1

Comment: I wrote it slowly thus there already were comments once I submitted my answer. But you are right I should have checked before submitting my answer.

Comment: @PhilippSander I don't see a Answer by @ isaksson, if he decides to post a comment instead of an Answer, who would care if someone posts it as an Answer as long as it is correct so its an totally valid Answer